# Android UI Resizing because of keyboard?

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard, resize, fragment

I'm developing a chat application. Recently I changed the Chat, Activity (no lag)  to Fragment (so many lag when resizing) because I wanted to **build a flexible UI** but now there is my problem : When the keyboard show up or disappear the UI resizing is very laggy.

I tried to changed adjustpan and other inside the manifest -> not working

When I remove the recyclerview from de chat -> it works, no lag when the keyboard show up.

So I guess the problem is here (I'm not sure),
I noticed this error **RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**
I tried to fix it with other post on stackoverflow but no success. The error also appears when I scroll the recyclerview or when the keyboard appears.

When I have lot of messages inside my adapter it's very laggy when the view is resizing.

**About the architecture**
The MainActivity have one container.
the container can contain fragments : FamilyFragment, SettingFragment, RootChatFragment

RootChatFragment -> building flexible UI (Contact Fragment and ChatFragment) or just Contact Fragment if it's mobile view

Can someone help me ? (sorry for my bad english)

Here a screenshot when I close the keyboard.
[image: laggyyyyyyy]

**UPDATED, FIXED**

Using **android:layout_weight="value"** was the problem but I don't know why.

Old one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.myapp.fragments.SpaceContact"
    android:id="@+id/contact_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.myapp.fragments.SpaceChat"
    android:id="@+id/chat_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

New one without lag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.myapp.fragments.SpaceContact"
    android:id="@+id/contact_fragment"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.myapp.fragments.SpaceChat"
    android:id="@+id/chat_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```